# Need Help Correct Regular Expression Redirect Code

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have custom permalinks with this code

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

and now switching to another custom permalinks

```
%postname%.html
```

so obviously all my content is now 404 not found, in yoast redirect setting there are Correct Regular Expression Redirect options or I could use htaccess to redirect my old content

anyone can help me with the code or suggestion for redirecting via yoast or htacces ??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* your existing WordPress directives, you could do something like the following to redirect the old permalink:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d\d/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path less the slash prefix.

`\d{4}/` - matches the 4-digit year, followed by a slash.

`\d\d/` - matches the 2-digit month number, followed by a slash.

`([\w-]+\.html)` - matches the *postname* and `.html` extension. The surrounding parentheses make this into a *capturing group* which is then referenced in the *substitution string* with the `$1` backreference. `[\w-]` matches characters in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen). If your *postname* can contain any other characters then these will need to be added to this character class (although the hyphen must appear *last*).

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues in case anything goes wrong. 301 (permanent) redirects are persistently cached by the browser by default.

Comment: Thank you ..works perfectly on the new URL and archive pages